# Debugging SP solution on different server

Tags: 2013, 2010, visual-studio, visual-web-part, debugging

Can we debug a SP 2010/2013 custom solution like Visual Web Part on a different SharePoint site which is not available on local machine but on a different SharePoint server? I tried to put a site as shown below in image for debugging and this site is not available locally but on a different SharePoint server.

[image]

Comment: Take a look here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25719/is-it-possible-to-attach-to-a-process-on-a-sharepoint-server-through-visual-stud

Comment: @Cecilia correctly answered your question. One addition though, when you attach to process you will halt the w3wp.exe process. So be careful if you're doing it on production environment on business hours.

Comment: But how can we overcome above exception thrown? Why doesn't it allowed to put different SharePoint site than local site?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have come up with a solution to the above exception. Yes we can overcome the above exception and can locally create SharePoint Solution without having SharePoint locally installed and can remotely debug through a local machine.

I have posted detailed step on my blog:

[Remote Debugging a SharePoint 2013 Farm Solution in Visual Studio 2013](http://sharepointdecode.blogspot.in/2017/02/remote-debugging-sharepoint-2013-farm.html)